# How can I see the year, when I command that last in unix system

Tags: linux

I'm korean and not familiar with english, but I'm asking to.
I'm using CentOS 5.5 and when I commanded 'last' to see who are logged in system, all logs don't have any informantions for year. They only have day, month and time as below.

`root     pts/0        100.100.100.100  Sat May 24 03:52   still logged in

root     tty1                          Sat May 24 03:52   still logged in

reboot   system boot  2.6.18-194.el5   Sat May 24 03:50          (00:02)

root     pts/2        211.45.57.232    Fri May 23 06:03 - crash  (21:47)

root     pts/0        211.45.60.5      Sat May 17 09:17 - crash (6+18:33)

root     pts/0        211.45.57.232    Sat May 17 08:54 - 09:17  (00:22)

root     pts/1        100.100.100.100  Sat May 17 05:47 - 06:30 (6+00:42)

root     pts/0        100.100.100.100  Sat May 17 05:32 - 07:40  (02:07)

reboot   system boot  2.6.18-194.el5   Sat May 17 05:32         (6+22:20)

root     pts/1        100.100.100.100  Fri Jan 24 21:27 - 22:05  (00:38)

root     pts/0        100.100.100.100  Fri Jan 24 17:44 - crash (112+11:48) 
root     pts/1        100.100.100.100  Fri Jan 24 10:42 - 14:51  (04:08)

root     pts/0        100.100.100.100  Fri Jan 24 09:37 - 12:05  (02:27)

root     pts/0        100.100.100.100  Fri Jan 24 05:51 - 05:51  (00:00)

root     pts/0        100.100.100.100  Fri Jan 24 05:50 - 05:51  (00:00)

root     tty1                          Fri Jan 24 05:50 - crash (112+23:41) 
reboot   system boot  2.6.18-194.el5   Fri Jan 24 05:49         (119+22:03) 
root     tty1                          Sat Jul  2 02:58 - down   (00:00)

reboot   system boot  2.6.18-194.el5   Sat Jul  2 02:56          (00:02)

root     tty1                          Sat Jul  2 02:51 - down   (00:04)

reboot   system boot  2.6.18-194.el5   Sat Jul  2 02:49          (00:06)

root     tty1                          Sat Jul  2 02:37 - down   (00:00)

root     tty1                          Sat Jul  2 02:35 - 02:37  (00:01)

reboot   system boot  2.6.18-194.el5   Sat Jul  2 02:34          (00:03)`

All I want to know is what year they have logged in.
Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is use the -t switch for each year:

`last -t 20140101000000`

This will show you logins before 2014-01-01 00:00:00. That is up to and including year 2013.

`last -t 20130101000000`

This will show you logins before 2013-01-01 00:00:00. That is up to and including year 2012.

And so forth doing one step for all years you have in your log.

Comment: I'm curious, does it only work since the last reboot, or further ?

Comment: Kwaio: The example I commented in you post comes from a server which had about 3-4 reboots during the last couple of years because of relocation (wtmp begins Sat Jan  7 23:09:33 2012)

Answer (score 7):

`last -F`
worked for me on CentOS 6.7.

`last -F reboot` gives a log of when the server was rebooted.

Though I gather that the -F switch doesn't work on some systems, like Solaris.  It's apparently part of GNU's `last`, though.

Thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97597/174520

Answer (score -1):

Like most command, you will get the year information only if the date is older than 365 days.

Meaning we're the 2014 May 22th, so 2013 May 23th will display just as "May 23th (hour)" but 2013 May 21 will display 2013 in stead of the hour.

Comment: This is wrong! Just look at his own example. July 2 of last year had no year in it!

Comment: as far as I know, July 2nd is less that 365 days ago, if it's 2013

Comment: Yeah, right. It was wroing, but I'd like to say that thank you for your answers.

Comment: That is indeed right. But you can still check a server with several years worth of lastlog and see that year does not appear. Example with host anonymized: bgs@HOST:~% last -t 20130101000000| head -1
bgs      pts/0        HOSTNAME     Fri Aug 24 15:16    gone - no logout